# Interactive Heatmap / Matrix Visualization

Tags: matrix, visualization, google-visualization

I would like to display on a webpage a heatmap (matrix) that I generate in R. 
The matrix I have looks like this, but in my case the size is 300x300.

[image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-38wWn7KD6v0/TgTJskG1ujI/AAAAAAAAC5g/0k33b0L5fL8/s1600/heatmap.png]

Basically I am looking for an interactive clustering, which would look like this :

http://online.wsj.com/article/SB125993225142676615.html#articleTabs%3Dinteractive

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/matrix.html

I would like to be able to clic on a branch which would then highlight the selected group/text, and fade out the rest of the matrix.

I have had a look around and cannot find much. I don't even know what language I should use for this ? JSON, Flash, HTML5, javascript, google charts ?

Any comments and advices would be extremely appreciated here.

Thanks.

Comment: have you find a solution for this problem. I am also interested to do interactive heatmaps.

Answer (score 5):

I think that InCHlib - Interactive Cluster Heatmap library could be the solution.

Available from http://openscreen.cz/software/inchlib.

Answer (score 1):

Google Visualization provides this heatmap option:
http://informatics.systemsbiology.net/visualizations/heatmap/bioheatmap.html

There's also this project that adapted it for more advanced uses and actually includes mouse-overs and tool-tips, as well as line magnification:
http://code.google.com/p/visquick/

You may also want to take a look at jQuery Flot, but be warned that WSJ uses a super expensive company called Tableau for data visualization and you are unlikely to find that level of visualization eye candy in an open source or free to use package.

Comment: Hi, well the http://vis.systemsbiology.net/visquick/examples/omics_heatmap/ seems to get close to what I want to do I guess.

Comment: this link seems to be broken as for 1/6/2015: http://informatics.systemsbiology.net/visualizations/heatmap/bioheatmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I had the same requirement. To create a Clustergram (Heatmap + Dendrogram) for a hierarchical clustering results.

There is no direct solution for this. I used  ProtovisGWT (Choosel) to create dendrogram and heatmap seperatley and later combnied them.

If you just want js library you can use just protovis or d3.js to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JavaScript for this task. Save your heatmap as SVG in R

```
svg("mymap.svg")
heatmap(...)
dev.off()
```

And then embed it into an HTML document as object

```
    <object id="test-svg" width="800" height="600" 
type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>
```

Now, you can use JavaScript or ECMAScript to do all kinds of manipulations. I recommend to read one of the various online tutorials on this topic. E.g., you could get started with this one: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/using-javascript-control-svg

Answer (score 0):

Treemap of D3.js solves this beautifully. See here

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/clustergrammer/ . It is not written in R, but you can make an interactive clustergram by uploading a matrix file in tab-separated format and you will be returned an interactive (reorderable, searchable, filterable, etc) and shareable web-based visualization

Answer (score 0):

[D3heatmap](https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap) provides interactive heatmaps with dendrograms in R based on the `heatmap` and `heatmap.2` interfaces. It includes single row and column selection but [does not currently allow](https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/issues/22) selection of dendrogram branches.